# Ajax POST Request in Larvael

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, post

I'm sending value named `text` from my `<script>` tag that is in a `.blade.php` file to controller by using `POST` Ajax request. If I do not write `$.post` function then it gives me output of text value in console. BUT when I write this Ajax request to send data to controller value do not pass. In short, I want to pass value from View to Controller and I am unable to do that. I have tried all YouTube tutorials and previous Stack Overflow questions. I also visited Laracasts but problem is not solved. Am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thank you.

shopReq.blade.php:

```
{{csrf_field()}}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ourItem').click(function(event){
                var text=$(this).text();
                $('#addItem').val(text);
                 console.log(text);
                $.post('shopReq',{'text':text,'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()}),function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Web.php:

```
Route::post('shopReq','UserController@special');
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{   
    public function special(Request $request){
        $articles = DB::table('shoppingtrips')->get();
        echo"DONE";
  //      return $request->all();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get on the console as output of `console.log(data);` ? Also try to replace `$.post('shopReq',{'text':text,'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()}),function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });`  

**with**

`$.post('shopReq',{'text':text, '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()}, function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });` then tell us the output of the console after this edit too please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `layout.blade.php` file add this to your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // laravel ajax helpers
    var APP_URL ={!! json_encode(url('/')) !!}; 
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then, in your view, do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ourItem').click(function(event){
            var text=$(this).text();
            $('#addItem').val(text);
            console.log(text);


            $.ajax({
                url: APP_URL+'/shopReq',
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    text: text
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In your controller, do this:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{   
    public function special(Request $request){
        $text = $request->input('text'); 
        // do stuff with $text 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below `ajax` syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your route',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        key1: value1
        // you can send more such key value pair here
    },

    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    success: function(response){

    }
});
```

Don't forget to add `CSRF-TOKEN`, otherwise you will get the 500 (Internal Server Error) as it is required with post request.

Comment: We put `$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
            }
        });` in our layout.blade file so that we dont have to deal with the token on a per call basis

Comment: I used your way, but It does not work. It is not giving any output in console as I added `console.log("Success")`  in success function.

Comment: I wrote `url: '/shopReq'` but it gives me error: 
`POST XHR http://localhost/shopReq [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 16ms]`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code. Specifically, there is an extra closing parenthesis at the end of your `$.post` function call, which should be removed. This is likely preventing the data from being passed to the controller.

Corrected version of the `$.post` call:

```
$.post('shopReq', {'text': text, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Also, it's worth noting that the `echo` statement in your controller will only send a plain text response back to the client

```
return response()->json(['message' => 'DONE']);
```

#### If this Not Work You can use this syntax of ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ourItem').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('#addItem').val(text);
    console.log(text);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'shopReq',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        text: text,
        _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
});
```